# Use the SAP LDAP connector to modify OU structure?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, abap

Does anyone know if the SAP LDAP connector can be used to modify the AD OU structure as well?

This SAP document briefly describes how to set it up and change user accounts. Can it also be used to create and modify the AD OU tree?
http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-3431

The business need is to create a solution that will create the AD structure and populate it with employees based on data from the SAP HR module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a set of function to act on a LDAP : LDAP_READ/UPDATE/DELETE/CREATE (group function FSLDAP_EXT). These function can be used to perform aby operation on a ldap (user or OU). you are only limited by the configuration (rights) of the user in the LDAP.

We used these to update organisation and users on a project with 105000 users and 12000 organizational units. Full comparaison (removing people present in LDAP and no more active in SAP, adding people that are new in sap, and comparing the attribute values for the others and updating if needed) took something like one hour.

Otherwise, afaik, the functionnalities described in your document only works for users.